# Algorithm to recursively search Git repo for a string

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, string-search

I am working on a project to automate the code review process for a team of engineers. Basically, what happens is every time an engineer makes a change to a file, before those changes are pushed to Github, they need to figure out what other files are being impacted by that change and add the engineers in charge of those files to view and approve that change. Right now, the person who made the change would manually do the following things: check which function the change occurred in, use the text search feature of an IDE (such as VS code) to see where that function is being used in the entire repo, go through all those search results and check which functions in other files is calling the original function, and then do a search for those functions. They would recursively search for functions until one of a group of designated files called "base files" appear in the search results. Separate engineers are in charge of separate base files, so once a base file appears in the search process, the person who made the change would need to add the engineer in charge of that base file to approve the change because the functionality of that file is potentially impacted by that change. We are trying to find a way to automate these manual steps.

I was wondering if there are any known algorithms that can be used to accomplish something like this. I am thinking of using graphs or trees, but I am not sure which specific graph or tree algorithms I should use.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, searching for strings is not good enough.

```
mark all base files
make call graph, directed graph (might not be acyclic)
do a BFS from changed file and log all Base files
```

Doxygen can generate some call graphs, or maybe there already is some Clang/LLVM call graph builder.